# Button dependant on database information in android

Tags: android, mysql

As the title says, I have a MySQL database with a products table. Some are in stock and some are not. In my app, when I list products I can click on a single one to show details fragment and another that you use in order to fill a form to order a product. Is it possible to make the "Order Product" button or even that whole fragment unavailable in case the product is listed as "not available" in the database?

Comment: if you get Product unavailable from your MySql database you should just make button unclickable.

Comment: Exactly my point, but is there a way to be unable to click the whole order product fragment?

Comment: `button.setClickable(false);`

Comment: right, so it's the same for clicking a fragment.. I will just include that at the end of getting the products from the database. thank you!